# Odds ratio calculation of metabin function

Tags: r, meta-analysis, odds-ratio

I'm having some trouble understanding how the Metabin function from the meta package in R calculates the odds ratio.

For example: I have an experimental group with 9 events and n = 20, and a control group with 11 events and n = 20. My understanding is that the odds ratio is calculated as:

$\Large \frac{\frac{e.events}{e.n}}{\frac{c.events}{c.n}} = \frac{\frac{9}{20}}{\frac{11}{20}} =$ $.8181$.

However, when I run the metabin function with sm = "OR", I get .67.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your calculation of the odds ratio is wrong. Have another look at the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio#A_motivating_example.2C_in_the_context_of_the_rare_disease_assumption) for the odds ratio. The OR in this case is calculated as $(9/11)/(11/9)\approx 0.67$.